# Bash move files matching a pattern to new folder

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I know there are similar questions to mine but I don't understand regular expressions at all so here's my new question:

I have a bunch of files in a folder. I need to move some files into another folder which match a certain pattern (anything with '`_GLM_`') using Bash. The source folder is called `/SingleScale` and the destination file is `/NotUsing`. Here's an example filename:

```
/SingleScale/Leopardus wiedii_GLM_canhtglad_s4_mean.csv
```

I tried:

```
cp /SingleScale/*_GLM_*.csv /NotUsing/
```

Comment: normally with `cp` without `-v` for verbose output, it would copy silently. does `ls /SingleScale/*_GLM_*.csv` shows any files there? or `ls /NotUsing/*_GLM_*.csv`?

Comment: Your command looks okay, only use `mv` to move files instead of `cp` (copy).

Comment: Can I be sure that using mv /SingleScale/*_GLM_*.csv /NotUsing/ I will refrain from moving files which fail to meet this pattern, for example I do not want to move the file: /SingleScale/Leopardus wiedii_GAM_canhtglad_s4_mean.csv

Answer (score 1):

Be careful :

- in Bash, using wildcards (such as `*`) to select which files to `cp`, `mv`, ... is not **regular expressions**. It's a Bash **internal pattern matching system** ([details](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns), [details with examples](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/pattern-matching-bash)).
- your files have a space in their name, which is fine but can make things complex when using the shell :

  - the space character is a field separator :

    ```
    cp file1 file2 myDir
    ```

    will copy the files `file1` and `file2` into the `myDir` directory, while :

    ```
    cp Leopardus wiedii_GLM_canhtglad_s4_mean.csv myDir
    ```

    will fail because there are no `Leopardus` nor `wiedii_GLM_canhtglad_s4_mean.csv` files.
  - it's possible to workaround this :

    - with quotes (simple or double quotes makes no difference in this case) :

      ```
      cp 'Leopardus wiedii_GLM_canhtglad_s4_mean.csv' myDir
      ```

      the downside being wildcards conflict with quotes...
    - by escaping the space character with a `\` :

      ```
      cp Leopardus\ wiedii_GLM_canhtglad_s4_mean.csv myDir
      ```

Apart from this, your command looks ok (except using `mv` rather than `cp` to actually move files). D you have further details / error message ?

Comment: since when [file name globbing](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) is bash internal?